# EF Core - Need to use Expression to force preloading of child entities

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am writing an Azure function application using .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core. I need to use Expression to grab all Employee records together with their messages and roster entries. Employee table is defined to be referenced by Message and RosterEntry tables through their foreign keys. However, with lazy loading, if I query by DbContext.Employee and then use `Include` keyword, Messages and RosterEntries will not be loaded and thus will throw error "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" when I try to update Employee records. I cannot turn off lazy loading, as it is a requirement of the project. The only option is to force (manually) preload Messages and RosterEntries into each Employee record. I have tried to use `Expression` like below

```
List<Expression<Func<Employee, object>>> expressions = new List<Expression<Func<Employee, object>>>();

if (includeMessages)
{
    Func<Employee, object> func = f => f.Messages;
    Expression<Func<Employee, object>> expr = e => func(e);
    expressions.Add(expr);
}

if (includeRosterEntries)
{
    Func<Employee, object> func = f => f.RosterEntries;
    Expression<Func<Employee, object>> expr = e => func(e);
    expressions.Add(expr);
}

var result = Find(f => f.Messages.Any(a => a.Id == messageId), false, null, expressions.ToArray());

return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I ran, it gave me the following exception.

> The expression 'Invoke(__func_1, e)' is invalid inside an 'Include'
> operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't =>
> t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use
> casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t =>
> (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be
> filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending),
> Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related
> data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Could someone please check the code above and let me know if I missed anything? Thanks.

Comment: You are getting the exception because the Include operation expects a property access expression, but you are providing a delegate invocation. You should directly use the property access expressions in your expressions list.. so inside each if statement, add the entry alone, for example inside the includeRosterEntries if statement, inside you just need this:
 expressions.Add(e => e.RosterEntries);